# xml - length of sublist in list - TypeError: len() of unsized object

Tags: python, xml, count, compression, typeerror

I use **IronPython 2.7** and **ElementTree**.

**Code description:**
I get all count nodes below AX. I append every node in lyst. After that i need the length of every sublist in `lyst`.

This is only a example xml. My real xml is much bigger and more complicated.

**xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>

    <ex>
         <top>
                <AX>
                    <count>a</count>
                    <count>b</count>
                    <count>c</count>
                </AX>
                <AX>
                    <count>a</count>
                </AX>
                <AX>
                    <count>a</count>
                    <count>b</count>
                    <count>c</count>
                    <count>d</count>
                </AX>
        </top>
    </ex>
</main>
```

**code:**

```
import clr
import sys
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib")
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

uniStr = unicode(open(path, 'r').read())
fixed = uniStr.encode('ascii', 'replace')
fixed.decode('utf-8', 'replace')
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(fixed))
root = tree.getroot()

lyst=[]
count=[]
xpath=".//top//AX"
xpath2=".//count"

count_match = root.findall(xpath)

for elem in count_match:
    subelem=elem.iterfind(xpath2)
    lyst.append(subelem)

count.append(map(len,lyst))
#count.append([len(x) for x in lyst])

print count
```

I expect: `count[3,1,4]`,but got this Error: python `TypeError: len() of unsized object`.

**Edit:**
With List Comprehensions: count.append([len(x) for x in lyst])

Same error: `TypeError: len() of unsized object`.

How can i count the objects in the sublists?

Comment: Your list comprehension should look like this `count.append([len(x) for x in lyst])`, all tough you might receive another error afterwards. btw: I suggest you use list comprehension for `lyst` as well. Saves you 3 lines!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is easy, the elements in `lyst` are generators so you can not ask their length. You have to convert them into a list first `count = [len(list(x)) for x in lyst]`.

Now the output will be

```
[3, 1, 4]
```

as expected.

If you use PyCharm then you can easily found this by debuging the code. Here is where it crashes:

[image]

I also recommend you to use list comprehension

```
lyst = [elem.iterfind(xpath2) for elem in count_match]
```

Comment: Thx for your help! I use Dynamo (can't use other programming environment) and there is no debugger:(.

Comment: I see. In that case you can use `print` around the line numbers where you expect the crash. Good luck with your project.